# Highlight a menu link when that page loaded

Tags: asp.net

I am working with a website. I am using a master page for web pages. I need to highlight the menu link when according page appears. Highlight means some color also.. I tried but when loading the page, the color for link is showing. But the page loaded, the color disappears..
I wrote the code for the color in master page page load event. The code is as follows.

So how I can highlight the link buttons according to page loads??

Please help...

Thank you in advance....

Comment: The code is as follows............. ? 404 no code found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your link button is in master page.
So write  a java script in page's source code as follows.

```
<script>
    var link=document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbtnHome")%>');
    link.style.color='red';
</script>
```

This helps you.