# Highlight the portion of the page that was linked to by #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say that the user clicks on a link that links to:

```
www.yoursite.com/page2#section1
```

Of course, because there is an id at the end, the page is loaded with with the focus on the #section1 element.

**How do I make it so that the #section1 element is also highlighted?**

Stackoverflow uses something like this when users [link to a particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792168/highlight-a-menu-link-when-that-page-loaded/17792315#17792315).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:target` pseudo class:

```
.section:target { background: red; }

<div class="section" id="section1"> <-- would have a red background
```

It's not supported natively in IE8 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        $(hash).addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```